# Python same Network Card Game

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, ip

So I'm doing this python basics course and my final project is to create a card game. At the bottom of the instructions I get this

> For extra credit, allow 2 players to play on two different computers that are on the same network. Two people should be able to start identical versions of your program, and enter the internal IP address of the user on the network who they want to play against. The two applications should communicate with each other, across the network using simple HTTP requests. Try this library to send requests:

> http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

> http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

> And try Flask to receive them:

> http://flask.pocoo.org/

> The 2-player game should only start if one person has challenged the other (by entering their internal IP address), and the 2nd person has accepted the challenge. The exact flow of the challenge mechanism is up to you.

I already investigated how flask works and kind of understand how python-requests works too. I just can't figure out how to make those two work together. If somebody could explain what should I do or tell me what to watch or read I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You're expected to show what you've done to tackle the problem and ask a more specific question. Without edits, this question will likely be closed as too broad.

Answer (score 0):

it would be nice to see how far you've come before answer (as hmm suggested you in a comment), but i can tell you something theorical about this.
What you are talking about is a client-server application, where server need to elaborate the result of clients actions.
What i can suggest is to learn about REST API, that you can use to let client and server to communicate in a easy way. Your clients will send http requests to server exposed APIs.
From what you wrote, you have a basically constraints that should be respected during client and server communication, here reasumed:

- Someone search for your ip and send you a challenge request
- You have received a challenge that you refuse or accept; only if you accept the challenge you can start the game

As you can see from the project specifications the entire challenge mechanism is up to you, so you can decide the best for you.

I would begin start thinking to a possible protocol that make use of REST API to start initial communication between client and server and let you define a basic challenge mechanism.
Enjoy programming :).

Comment: Thank you. You helped me a lot. I just want to know if you can help me with one more thing:
I've solved everything else but one thing. Let's say I have a database of BlogPosts and I display the database in the '/posts' route. So far I've been able to make both client and host be able to post, delete and update BlogPosts. I want to do the following: When someone edits, deletes or creates a post, everyone in '/posts' get's redirected to '/posts' (or refreshed for short), so that they can see the changes in the BlogPosts.

Comment: Your `/post` route can handle both **GET** and **POST** request where, edit, delete or create options are made with a post request that at the end redirect to itself. In this case the redirect with this code `return redirect(url_for('posts'))` generates a get request on the same route, that execute a different code such as the render of the tamplate that contains all the posts. You can define this behavior by checking the method by which the route receives the requests with `request.method`. More info about this : [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_http_methods.htm)